# Tenant blacklisted while executing Google Explorer API

Tags: google-apis-explorer

I get the following error when trying to execute an API from Google API Explorer. I was using the default credentials of the Explorer.

I tried a few times to make the request go through and finally I got a blacklisted message.

What is the way forward from here?

Appreciate any help.

403

Show headers

```
{
 "error": {
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Tenant user@gmail.com is blacklisted.. Request ID for tracking: 14d4de455-5c77-4297-a771-752738685d1e:APAb7IRHRzYs3c4r45M8rrJfdrKo3vStDQ==",
  "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
 }
}
```